# Play Activator with Nexus as a repository proxy

Tags: playframework, sbt, nexus, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to use Play's Typesafe activator but ran into a problem.
I'm on a corporate network and normally use oss nexus as a dependency proxy.
I've downloaded play, extracted it to a folder in the root of my disk (C:\activator). When I try to run it, it just gets no where as it can't reach maven or ivy repositories.

Next, placed the repository configuration at C:\users\myuser.sbt\repositiories, with the following content:

```
[repositories]
  local
  my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  my-maven-proxy-releases: http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/
```

Follwogin with I've read from a number of topics,also placed the .credentials file in C:\users\myuser.ivy.credentials

```
realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager
host=myserver
user=admin
password=myadminpass
```

I can see from the updated.log that SBT recognizes my nexus repository and attempts to use it but doensn't make use of the credentials I've configured in .credentials.

Here's my updated.log

```
setting 'ivy.default.settings.dir' to 'jar:file:/C:/activator/activator-launch-1.3.2.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'C:\Windows\System32\.'
setting 'ivy.default.conf.dir' to 'jar:file:/C:/activator/activator-launch-1.3.2.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings'
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SshResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VsftpResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.version.PatternVersionMatcher in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.trigger.LogTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntBuildTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IvyRepResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.signer.bouncycastle.OpenPGPSignatureGenerator in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.conflict.RegexpConflictManager in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.SFTPResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.updatesite.UpdateSiteResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.ant.AntCallTrigger in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.MirroredURLResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.packager.PackagerResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.DualResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.VfsResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.JarResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define new type: class not found: org.apache.ivy.osgi.obr.OBRResolver in [] nor Ivy classloader
impossible to define glob matcher: org.apache.ivy.plugins.matcher.GlobPatternMatcher was not found.
setting 'jline.esc.timeout' to '0'
setting 'java.runtime.name' to 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment'
setting 'sun.boot.library.path' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\bin'
setting 'java.vm.version' to '25.40-b25'
setting 'user.country.format' to 'PT'
setting 'activator.home' to '//C:/activator'
setting 'java.vm.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'java.vendor.url' to 'http://java.oracle.com/'
setting 'path.separator' to ';'
setting 'java.vm.name' to 'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM'
setting 'file.encoding.pkg' to 'sun.io'
setting 'user.country' to 'US'
setting 'user.script' to ''
setting 'sun.java.launcher' to 'SUN_STANDARD'
setting 'sun.os.patch.level' to ''
setting 'java.vm.specification.name' to 'Java Virtual Machine Specification'
setting 'user.dir' to 'C:\Windows\System32'
setting 'java.runtime.version' to '1.8.0_40-b26'
setting 'java.awt.graphicsenv' to 'sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment'
setting 'java.endorsed.dirs' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\endorsed'
setting 'os.arch' to 'amd64'
setting 'java.io.tmpdir' to 'C:\Users\netona1\AppData\Local\Temp\'
setting 'line.separator' to '
'
setting 'java.vm.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'user.variant' to ''
setting 'os.name' to 'Windows 8.1'
setting 'sun.jnu.encoding' to 'Cp1252'
setting 'java.library.path' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient\;C:\dev\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\netona1\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\activator;C:\dev\pathstuff;C:\Users\netona1\AppData\Roaming\npm;.'
setting 'java.specification.name' to 'Java Platform API Specification'
setting 'java.class.version' to '52.0'
setting 'sun.management.compiler' to 'HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers'
setting 'os.version' to '6.3'
setting 'user.home' to 'C:\Users\netona1'
setting 'user.timezone' to 'Europe/London'
setting 'java.awt.printerjob' to 'sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob'
setting 'file.encoding' to 'Cp1252'
setting 'java.specification.version' to '1.8'
setting 'java.class.path' to 'C:\activator\activator-launch-1.3.2.jar'
setting 'user.name' to 'NETONA1'
setting 'jline.shutdownhook' to 'false'
setting 'java.vm.specification.version' to '1.8'
setting 'sun.java.command' to 'C:\activator\activator-launch-1.3.2.jar'
setting 'java.home' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre'
setting 'sun.arch.data.model' to '64'
setting 'user.language' to 'en'
setting 'java.specification.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'user.language.format' to 'pt'
setting 'awt.toolkit' to 'sun.awt.windows.WToolkit'
setting 'java.vm.info' to 'mixed mode'
setting 'java.version' to '1.8.0_40'
setting 'java.ext.dirs' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext'
setting 'sun.boot.class.path' to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\classes'
setting 'java.vendor' to 'Oracle Corporation'
setting 'sun.stderr.encoding' to 'cp850'
setting 'file.separator' to '\'
setting 'java.vendor.url.bug' to 'http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/'
setting 'sun.io.unicode.encoding' to 'UnicodeLittle'
setting 'sun.cpu.endian' to 'little'
setting 'sun.stdout.encoding' to 'cp850'
setting 'sun.desktop' to 'windows'
setting 'sun.cpu.isalist' to 'amd64'
setting 'ivy.default.ivy.user.dir' to 'C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2'
setting 'ivy.home' to 'C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2'
setting 'ivy.cache.dir' to 'C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\cache'
no default cache defined: set to C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\cache
setting 'ivy.checksums' to 'sha1,md5'
setting 'ivy.basedir' to 'C:\Users\netona1\.sbt\boot'
setting 'basedir' to 'C:\Users\netona1\.sbt\boot'
:: resolving dependencies :: org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi;1.0
    confs: [default]
    validate = true
    refresh = false
resolving dependencies for configuration 'default'
== resolving dependencies for org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi;1.0 [default]
loadData of org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi;1.0 of rootConf=default
== resolving dependencies org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi;1.0->org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11 [default->default(compile)]
loadData of org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11 of rootConf=default
    using redefined-public to resolve org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
redefined-public: Checking cache for: dependency: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11 {default=[default(compile)]}
redefined-public: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: tried C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\cache\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\ivy-1.11.xml
redefined-public: no latest strategy defined: using default
local: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: tried C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\cache\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\ivy-1.11.xml
     trying C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml
        tried C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml
    local: resource not reachable for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: res=C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml
     trying C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar
        tried C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar
    local: resource not reachable for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: res=C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar
    local: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
my-ivy-proxy-releases: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: tried C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\cache\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\ivy-1.11.xml
     trying http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
        tried http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
try to get credentials for: Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager@myserver
authentication: k='Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager@myserver' c='null'
HTTP response status: 401 url=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
    my-ivy-proxy-releases: resource not reachable for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: res=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
    my-ivy-proxy-releases: no ivy file found for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
my-maven-proxy-releases: no namespace defined: using system
    no ivy file in cache for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: tried C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\cache\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\ivy-1.11.xml
     trying http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
        tried http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
try to get credentials for: Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager@myserver
authentication: k='Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager@myserver' c='null'
HTTP response status: 401 url=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
    my-maven-proxy-releases: resource not reachable for org/fusesource/jansi#jansi;1.11: res=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
     trying http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
        tried http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
try to get credentials for: Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager@myserver
authentication: k='Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager@myserver' c='null'
HTTP response status: 401 url=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
CLIENT ERROR: Unauthorized url=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
    my-maven-proxy-releases: resource not reachable for org/fusesource/jansi#jansi;1.11: res=http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
    my-maven-proxy-releases: no ivy file nor artifact found for org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
WARN:   module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11
WARN: ==== local: tried
WARN:   C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml
WARN:   -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:
WARN:   C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar
WARN: ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried
WARN:   http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml
WARN: ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried
WARN:   http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
WARN:   -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:
WARN:   http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar
Nbr of module to sort : 0
    resolved ivy file produced in cache
:: downloading artifacts ::
:: resolution report :: resolve 360ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN:   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
WARN:   :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found
WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Nbr of module to sort : 0
    report for org.scala-sbt#boot-jansi;1.0 default produced in C:\Users\netona1\.sbt\boot\resolution-cache\org.scala-sbt-boot-jansi-default.xml
    resolve done (360ms resolve - 0ms download)

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

      C:\Users\netona1\.ivy2\local\org.fusesource.jansi\jansi\1.11\jars\jansi.jar

    ==== my-ivy-proxy-releases: tried

      http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/ivy-releases/org.fusesource.jansi/jansi/1.11/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== my-maven-proxy-releases: tried

      http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom

      -- artifact org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11!jansi.jar:

      http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/allreps/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.11: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
java.lang.RuntimeException: not found
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:238)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:292)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:714)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:799)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:722)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:594)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:234)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:106)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:101)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:352)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jansiLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:178)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jansiLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:173)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:150)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:366)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
    at xsbt.boot.Pre$.error(Pre.scala:26)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.xsbt$boot$Update$$lockedApply(Update.scala:106)
    at xsbt.boot.Update$$anon$4.call(Update.scala:100)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.apply(Update.scala:101)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:352)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jansiLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:178)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jansiLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:173)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:150)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:366)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
```

Can anyone shed some light on the proper configuration? I still can't get past the activator installation step

Comment: Have you tried to setup the proxy into [USER_FOLDER]/.activator/.activatorconfig.txt file?

Comment: Isn't that for an http proxy? If not, could you give a little detail about the file contents? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line on your plugins.sbt (located at /project/plugins.sbt) file:

```
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
```

Also, in order to SBT get plugins from your repo, you need to pass -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true when calling activator or sbt. You could set environment variable SBT_OPTS, example:

```
SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true"
```

Let me know if you run into any problems. Good luck